# Google Sheet to Bigquery Integration

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

I have successfully connected my Google Sheet to BigQuery using the 'create table -> table source -> drive -> sheet's URL' process.

My question is, can I add new data from the Google Sheet to BigQuery without affecting the existing data in BigQuery if I delete a row or data from the sheet?

In essence, I want to automate the 'add data' process without automating the 'remove/delete data' process from the sheet to BigQuery.

Comment: You can create an external table which refers to google sheets on google drive. this way it provides direct access to whatever data is in google sheets. see this page https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-drive#create_external_tables

Comment: BigQuery created on the Google Sheet is a type of the external table, which means, that the table does not store results itself, but is a kind of a link to the Google Sheet, and the data is being gathered when invoking the query on the table. If you would like to preserve the data somewhat consider data materialization - e.g. to run scheduled query on a daily basics to query the external table and than save the results to the native table.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add new data to BigQuery from your Google Sheet without affecting existing data in BigQuery if you delete a row or data from the sheet. When you use the `create table -> table source -> drive -> sheet's URL` process to link your Google Sheet to BigQuery, it creates a snapshot of the data at that specific point in time. Any changes made to the Google Sheet after this initial snapshot won't be automatically reflected in the BigQuery table.

To automate the process of adding new data to BigQuery without affecting existing data, you can schedule regular updates or imports from the Google Sheet to BigQuery. This can be done using **Google Cloud Platform (GCP) services** like **Cloud Scheduler**, **Cloud Functions**, or **Google Apps Script**.

You can also go through the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-drive#create_external_tables) provided by @Bihag Kashikar.

Posting this answer as a Community Wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Please feel free to edit this answer for additional information and if there are other possible workarounds/direct solutions for this use case.